# Bash - Intersecting files

Tags: bash

So here I try to intersect all the files located in the current directory. Those files are of the following format

```
<number>
<number>
<number>
<number>
```

I have come up with the following script but it doesn't seem to work properly and I do not understand why.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Make a list with all the filenames of the directory.
declare -a files
for tfile in *.txt ; do 
    files+=($tfile)
done 

intersect()
{
    diff -y ${1} ${2} | # -y : --side-by-side
    grep -v "[>|<]"   | # -v : inverse grepping. 
    sed 's/\t.*//'    
}

# Intersect the first two files in the list so then
# I can perform accumulative intersection with loop

intersect ${files[0]} ${files[1]} > acc_int.txt 

for (( i=2; i<${#files[@]}; i++)); do

    intersect ${files[${i}]} acc_int.txt > acc_int.txt # This probably creates a problem
done
```

So the idea is that you always intersect a new file with the old ones. This "algorithm"/"method" has worked with python's pandas but now I try it with bash. So whats the problem here? The resulting file "acc_int.txt" has 0 entries and of course, the sets (files) have an intersection that is != 0.

Comment: Please paste your script there first: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `cat acc_int.txt > acc_int.txt` Think about it. You can't read and write to the same file at the same time.

Comment: Oh yeah... `files=(*.txt)` can be used instead of that first loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all numbers that appear in all files, it's a lot simpler and more efficient to use (GNU) `awk`:

```
gawk 'BEGINFILE { nfiles++ }
      { seen[$1]++ }
      END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
            for (n in seen)
              if (seen[n] == nfiles) print n
      }' *.txt
```

---

Alternatively, if the files are lexicographically sorted, you can use [`comm(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/comm.1.html) to get the intersection of two files:

```
comm -12 file1.txt file2.txt
```

which would simplify your script.